# More connections or download bigger data

Tags: ios, http, download, connection

What is more efficient? Divide the data into more connections or just put it all into one big connection?

Lets say we have a tableview which show a name of a person, when you select one row you move to another VC which show more info and in that view you can press a button to get even more info about that person.

Is it better to on the first VC to download ALL information for EVERY person in one big json and then use that to load the next views.

Or is it better to download on the first view just the names and maybe an id. And when you select a row you send that id to the server to download more info about just that person and so on.

My practical experience is that connections sometimes doesnt succeed so more connections could be dangerous, but the other way you only download the data you need.

What is the preferred method?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best practice is to lazy load. Make connections as and when they are necessary.

I take your point about 'connections failing' and, to a certain extent, that's true of mobile connections. However, in addition to a slower user interface, another caveat of 'one big download' is the fact that potentially by the time the user interacts with the data it's stale.